# How to shrink a disk that has unallocated space on it in VM Ware?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have a VM where I orginally put everything on one Disk, I had my D drive right next to my C drive. As my C Drive was running out of space I could not expand it because the D drive was right next to it.

I backed up my D Drive, removed it, and created a new disk that I put everything from my D Drive back onto and named it my D drive. And was able to expand my C drive back out to have more space and be healthy.

Great so whats the issue?

Well my original disk still have 250 GBs on it, which is WAY too much then I need just for my C Drive. See image here for my disk management window.

[image: Disk Management Screen Shot]

How can I get rid of this 97GB of unallocated space?

Comment: how is the virtual disk set to allocate? it may be that your disk file on the host is only 152GB, not 250. if that is the case, do you really care about resizing the disk?

Answer (score 0):

For VMWare Workstation (and likely Player Pro):

For a Windows Guest. shut down the guest machine(s), and then VMware Menu Bar, VM, Manage, and select Cleanup Disk.   Do this for each machine.

For a Linux Guest:  It needs to be running. Then issue the following command:

sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /

This will occur in two steps:

(1) Progress will show in the terminal window.
(2) Then a VMware sub window starts with the actual shrink.

I always shut down the Linux guest upon completion and start it up again.

As noted, do this for all Windows and all Linux guest machines.

Your machines needed to be set up with unallocated space in order for cleanup and shrink to work.

If you preallocated the disk space, it will be best overall to make a new machine and ensure the disk space is not preallocated.

Comment: Hey John, no disk cleanup did not help me. It gave me the option to clean my C or D Drive, but this isnt on a drive it is unallocated space.

Comment: Did you Pre-Allocate space for your machines?  That uses your disk space and you would need to make a new machine(s) with unallocated space. That allows cleanup and shrink to twork.

Comment: Yes I did pre-allocate space. Darn I really do not want to start from scratch.

Comment: Try this article  ....   https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Can-A-Compressed-Preallocated-VM-be-Changed-to-an-Expanding-One/td-p/1365552   ... Otherwise you may need to start from scratch.  I amended my answer to include the need for unallocated disk space for cleanup and shrink to work.

Comment: Another thing I saw is using VMware Converter to make a smaller machine. I have used VMware Converter to make bigger machines. It that does not work, you will need to build a new machine.

Comment: do you really need that 100GB on the host? if not, you don't NEED to do anything. just leave it be. alternately, there are lots of programs for cloning a system disk from one drive to another. you could boot the vm from one of them and clone your VM to a new drive, eventually deleting the old one

Comment: Frank, no I do not need that 100GB on the host. But I want to backup my VM and put in on an external drive and a OneDrive. I would rather not be storing an extra 100GB if it is not nessisary.

Comment: Yes I agree about the size backing up.  I backup my machines regularly. So as I noted in my answer, the easiest approach is to make a new machine and do not preallocate the space.  There is not any straightforward way to change a 100GB machine to unallocated.   So I think I have answered your question.